# How can I access error object of SequelizeJS (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have written following piece of code using 'sequelizeJS' and want to access error object to extract the validation message contained by the err object.

```
var userData = {name: "waqas", email: null};

db.User
  .create(userData)
  .success(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .error(function(err){
    console.log(err);  // want to get validation message from 'err' object

  });
```

The output of console.log(err) is:

```
{ [Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'email' cannot be null]
  code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`email`,`platform`,`email_flag`,`purchased_balance`,`subscription_balance`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'waqas\',NULL,\'ios\',true,0,0,\'2014-08-17 06:09:08\',\'2014-08-17 06:09:08\');' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is from the database, not from sequelize. You will need to set `allowNull: false` on your email column to get validation from sequelize

Comment: I want to access this error message. My question is How can I access the message present in this error object. I want to show the message in user interface.

Comment: The error is basically just a JS object. Try to iterate through all its properties and see if one has the data you are looking for `for (var attribute in err) {`